# Simple Graph in Ggplot2 and Plot.ly for R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm trying to create a very simple graph in R using ggplot2 and Plot.ly. I've got a dataset with about 10 pieces of information. I've read a few tutorials but all of R is lost on me.

This is what I've got, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
Library("ggplot2")
setwd("c:/Users/charlieecho/documents")
Name data set <- read.(“ATTACKS”, 1)
qplot(LMS, data= ATTACKS, geom=c("scattered"),           main="Number of attacks")
```

And...

```
 install.packages("plotly")
 library(plotly)
 setwd("c:/Users/charlieecho/documents")
Name data set <- read.(“ATTACKS”, 1)
plotly graph <- plot_ly(ATTACKS, x = ~number of attacks,   type = "box")
```

I know some people use the aes style to create a graph but that doesn't make any sense to me either.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) when you're asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do a simple ggplot and plotly for point plot.

```
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=Year, y=Attacks)) + geom_point()

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

The data, based on the google doc link:

```
dat <- structure(list(Year = c(1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1994, 
1995, 1996), Attacks = c(35, 28, 42, 32, 30, 32, 56, 60, 35)), .Names = c("Year", 
"Attacks"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

For a barplot:

```
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=Year, y=Attacks)) + 
       geom_bar(stat="identity")

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you so much.  So for Plotly just add "ggplotly(p)" where "ggplot" is in your example? Then add that to what I originally posted, with J.P.'s corrections?  For a bar chart I swap out "point" for "bar", correct?

Comment: If you're already starting with ggplot, just use ggplotly to convert it according. Added geom_bar example in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I can help a little bit.  You can't have spaces in variable names, so replace "Name data set" with:

```
 mydata <-
```

Then, what kind of file is your data in?  If it's in a .csv file named ATTACKS.csv, you'll want to use:

```
  mydata <- read.csv("ATTACKS.csv")
```

Then, in your qplot command, instead of using data=ATTACKS, you'll use:

```
  data = mydata
```

If you can share your data, I can try to make the graph, and answer with a complete working script.  But when you say, "create a very simple graph", what kind of graph? Time series, histogram, bar chart, etc.?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm looking for a bar chart and maybe a cheat sheet on how to change a few things like color and size, etc. Here's the link to my data, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KVNK0CJ79Yeeg9SVzEQLlEZP_vXQTF5t-oxN0fbHuUw/edit?usp=sharing